# OpenCV: Getting the total of Mat values

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there some openCV function that I can pass in a `cv::Mat` and get the sum of all values in them?

For example: `int cvSumFoo(Mat &srcMat)`; I'm expecting an int to come back

I create it like this:

```
srcMat= new Mat(rows, cols, CV_8U);
```

I would like to avoid creating my own loop if at all possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sum of elements in a matrix in open cv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874774/sum-of-elements-in-a-matrix-in-open-cv)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function 'sum' "calculates and returns the sum of array elements, independently for each channel."

You can find the information here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sum

Comment: Thank you! that did the trick. It always helps to use code already in openCV to keep your code clean. Things look better now.

Answer (score 9):

I know that the questioner *didn't ask* for the function in **Java-openCV**, but I still want to show how to do it in Java, because:

> 1. the "sum"-function in Java is named totally different and is in a *different* class
> 2. Java openCV API examples are sparse

The code for printing a sum in Java openCV is:

```
Core.sumElems(myMat);
```

Obvious is that, it is *not* a function of the "**Scalar**"-class and its name is *not* `sum()`.

Comment: I'm also using Java opencv - this was very helpful.

Comment: How do you get an integer value from this Scalar? Eg I am getting (12550,0,0,0)

Comment: @nette: Scalar myScalar = Core.sumElems(myMat); myScalar.val[0]; myScalar.val[1]; myScalar.val[2]; myScalar.val[3];