# Sum of elements in a matrix in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I need to sum all the elements in a matrix. I used the function

```
  sum(sum(A));
```

in matlab. Where `A` is a matrix of size 300*360.
I want to implement the same function in OpenCV. I used something like this.

```
  double s=cv::sum(cv::sum(A));
```

But there is error showing cannot convert scalar to double. How to fix this problem?

Comment: just as an aside, in Matlab it is  better to `sum(A(:))` instead of `sum(sum(A))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenCV: Getting the total of Mat values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156044/opencv-getting-the-total-of-mat-values)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Unlike Matlab, in opencv, `cv::sum(A)` sums along ALL dimensions and returns a single number (scalar) that is equal to Matlab's `sum(sum(A))`.
So, what you need is

```
double s = cv::sum(A)[0];
```

Comment: not quite correct: `cv::Scalar s = cv::sum(A);`  if that's a 1chan mat, it's : `double psum = cv::sum(A)[0];`

Comment: What does [0] stands for.Can anyone please explain?

Comment: `cv::sum` returns a `cv::Scalar` element. If you have a 3-channel image for example, the return value has 3 elements, one for each channel. So each channel is summed up independently. `[0]` would access the first value of that Scalar. For RGB images with BGR ordering (like mostly used in OpenCV), `[0]` of the Scalar would access the summed up "blue channel", '[1]' would be the sum of the "green channel" and '[2]' is the sum of the "red channel" in that example. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#sum

Comment: Can I pass a `Mat` object to this function

Comment: The reason it's done this way is that cv::Mat is runtime typed; the same cv::sum() is called regardless of whether the array actually contains uint8's, int16, float, etc; so all cases must return the same type. 'Scalar' contains 4 doubles, which accommodates all cases (up to 4 channels). Contrast with other matrix implementations which use compile-time typing, e.g. CImg<T> in which you generally have different function return types for different element types.

Comment: Use `cv::sum(cv::sum(A))[0]` to get the sum of sums scalar value in the multi-channel scenario

Comment: @Tom AFAIK that will not work, if I understand correctly `cv::sum` on a `Scalar` is an invariant, i.e. output is a copy of the input.

Comment: I wish I could put a _negative_ bounty on this answer :), it is so misleading as far as it concerns multiple channel images, and it doesn't give an explanation on why `[0]`

Answer (score 10):

In addition with [@Shai](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21875049/1714410) you can use;

```
double sum = cv::sum(A).val(0);
```

Comment: This also considers only the first channel in the case of a multi-channel (e.g. color) input image.

Answer (score 0):

[`Scalar cv::sum(InputArray src)`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga716e10a2dd9e228e4d3c95818f106722) returns a `Scalar` where each channel has been summed separately (input image must have between 1 to 4 channels). If what we are looking for is the sum of all the values across all channels, one further step is needed summing all elements of the returned `Scalar`. A one-liner solution could be using the [`dot`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/de/de1/classcv_1_1Matx.html#aff0ce90dadd68822c348b0bbae4a5f2a) product with a scalar filled with ones:

```
cv::sum(A).dot(cv::Scalar::ones());
```

This works universally also for single channel images, without adding significant extra computation.