# Summing BGR in each column of ROI? openCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, rgb

I am trying to sum together the BGR values of the entire column of a ROI of a camera image. Right now, I loop through the matrix, and assign each BGR value to a variable to put into my 2d vector. I am sure I am doing this wrong, and that there is a much better way.

```
        Vec3b rgbVal;

        for (int r = 0; r < img1.rows; ++r) {
            vector <double> colVal;
            for (int c = 0; c < img1.cols; ++c) {
                rgbVal = img1.at<Vec3b>(r, c); //Converts Mat image to Vec3b for BRG access
                //Accesses the BRG values of each pixel in the column of the ROI, and adds it to values
                values += static_cast<double>(rgbVal[0]) + static_cast<double>(rgbVal[1]) + static_cast<double>(rgbVal[2]);
                colVal.push_back(values);
            }
            j.push_back(colVal);
            values = 0;
        }
```

So in my ROI, I am trying to sum together ALL the BGR values of every pixel in each column. Can someone help me out with this and point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with that method?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be resetting it properly. I know my logic is wrong somewhere.

For example, when I put a black object over my camera and select a tiny ROI, my output is:

206  212  650  626  656  882  666  661  890  882  666  661  890  882  666  661  888  884  666  661  890  882  666  661  890  882  666  661  890  884  666  661  893  884  666  661  890  884  666  661  888

These numbers seem super inaccurate..

Comment: Did you check cv::sum, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21874774/sum-of-elements-in-a-matrix-in-opencv

Comment: You could use buit-in methods for this. Just apply a rol for each column and apply sum function. Besides that, everything seems good.

Comment: Yes I was aware of the sum function. I am pretty new to openCV so it was a but difficult to understand if the function did the correct values. So does sum add up the RGB values of each pixel?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does :D You can then access each channel just the way you are doing. Either way, your code seems fine.

Comment: Okay awesome! Thanks so much!

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] -- right now it's unclear what exactly is `img1` (I guess a `cv::Mat` with data type `CV_8UC3`), `values` (probably a `double`), `j` (a `std::vector<std::vector<double>`). | According to your description, I understand that you want as a result 1 number for each column? If that's the case, you're probably looking for something like [this](https://pastebin.com/wKmsqiXX) using `cv::reduce` and `cv::transform`.

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks so much!